# Reduce the font-size on small screens so words do not break

Tags: html, css

My page titles are short but with medium-long words, and I want the longest word of a sentence to fit the width of the screen.

**960px**

```
|                              |
|The Metropolitan Museum of Art|
|                              |
```

On mobile (screens lower than about 400px) I'd like to wrap the text as naturally happens, and to reduce the size so the longest word in that title dictates the font-size.

**460px**

```
|                |
|The Metropolitan|
|Museum of Art   |
```

or smaller

**320px**

```
|The    |
|The Metropolitan| <----- "Metropolitan" bleeds out of the page
|Museum |
|of Art |
```

Is there a rule that can reduce the font-size according to the "Metropolitan" word?

I don't want to break words: it's just bad typography.

I know I need media queries, that's not the problem. The problem is if I have a word like "supercalifragilistic" even if I set a media queries for 320px and font-size:12px it will leave either a space or bleedout.

Comment: My first thought is you might accomplish this by applying Scale via JavaScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale

Comment: you can use media query to reduce the font size below 320px

Comment: Wrap each individual word in a span and make each span non-breaking and 100% width?  (Not at my computer to test here, just spitballing)

Comment: did you try using     **word-wrap: break-word;**

Comment: I don't want to break word: it's just bad typography!!!

Comment: Media queries **are** the answer so I don't understand how you can say it's not.

Comment: @Rob even if i set 10 breakpoints i will still have very long words that won't break and will bleed out of the screen. I want the longest word of a sentence  to fit the width of the screen

Answer (score 2):

You can try and use fluid-typography

CSS:

```
/*
Font-size is fluid.
It will be 16px when it reaches 300px width of the viewport
and 30px when it reaches 1500px of the viewport. Beyond and below those 
breakpoints 
font-size will be also fluid but we can restrict this using @media queries.
For example we can restrict that after viewport has reached the width of 1500px
the font size will be set as the fixed point (e.g. 2em).
*/
HTML {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: calc(16px + (30 - 16) * (100vw - 300px) / (1500 - 300) );
}

/*
Notes:

-*- The rem unit:

* In IE9 and IE10, using rem with the shorthand `font` property will make the whole declaration invalid.
Also, these two browsers don’t support rem units on pseudo elements.

-*- Viewport units (vw, vh, vmin, vmax):

* IE11 and Edge don’t support the vmax unit.

-*- Calc:

* calc with px and viewport units might not work in Safari, so
we can replace px units with percentages, in order to use it with viewport 
units.

* calc with percentages is totally broken on IE (both 11 and Edge) 
so you can use a regular calc() function with the em unit,
followed by a -webkit-calc() function with the percentage unit

*/


@media screen and (min-width: 1500px) {

    HTML { 
     font-size: 1.875em; /*~30px*/ 
   }

}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Konrud/pen/jmWqqX) that I've found.

Answer (score 0):

If you want text's size be related to device size use relative measurement units like **vw**

Ex:

```
heading {
   font-size: 10vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting font size like this

```
html {
    font-size: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 460px)
html {
    font-size: 90%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px)
html {
    font-size: 80%;
}
```